# Using python to separate sentences into paragraphs

Tags: python, nltk, paragraphs

I need to use python to separate sentences into paragraphs for the video caption. I tried to use nltk.tokenize.texttiling but didn't get any results.
Here the excerpt of the text:

```
– [Voiceover] Bob Dylan is,
you must be 20 years old now,
aren't you?
– [Voiceover] Yeah, I must be 20.
(laughing)
– [Voiceover] Are you?
– [Voiceover] Yeah, I'm 20, I'm 20.
(guitar music)
My hands are cold.
It's a pretty cold studio.
– [Voiceover] The coldest studio.
– [Voiceover] Usually can do this.
There I just want to do it once.
(guitar strumming)
– [Voiceover] When I first heard Bob Dylan
was, I think, about three
years ago in Minneapolis.
– [Voiceover] At that time I
was just sort of doing nothing.
I was there working, I guess.
I was making pretend I was
going to school out there.
I'd just come there from South Dakota.
– [Voiceover] You've sung
now at Goody's here in town.
Have you sung at any of the coffee houses?
```

Comment: I've never head of such a thing. In any event, are you trying to parse transcripts of human conversation? Turning those into paragraphs seems entirely nonsensical - paragraphs are a way to organize human writing, and doesn't apply to human conversation.

Comment: How would you separate sentences into paragraphs? A paragraph is composed of sentences, but sentences are composed of words.

Comment: Sentences can be found using NLTK module, and then if the topic is changed completely between sentences then it is the indication of the new paragraph. This is how TextTiling is working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty easy, you can use regex to do this,
I did't know which format you want, but here is an example

```
import re

sentence = """
– [Voiceover] Bob Dylan is,
you must be 20 years old now,
aren't you?
– [Voiceover] Yeah, I must be 20.
(laughing)
– [Voiceover] Are you?
– [Voiceover] Yeah, I'm 20, I'm 20.
(guitar music)
My hands are cold.
It's a pretty cold studio.
– [Voiceover] The coldest studio.
– [Voiceover] Usually can do this.
There I just want to do it once.
(guitar strumming)
– [Voiceover] When I first heard Bob Dylan
was, I think, about three
years ago in Minneapolis.
– [Voiceover] At that time I
was just sort of doing nothing.
I was there working, I guess.
I was making pretend I was
going to school out there.
I'd just come there from South Dakota.
– [Voiceover] You've sung
now at Goody's here in town.
Have you sung at any of the coffee houses?

"""

start_re = re.compile(r'\–\s\[.*?\]')
result = re.split(start_re,sentence)
result = filter(lambda x:x, [s.replace('\n','').strip() for s in result])
print result
```

OUTPUT

```
["Bob Dylan is,you must be 20 years old now,aren't you?", 'Yeah, I must be 20.(laughing)', 'Are you?', "Yeah, I'm 20, I'm 20.(guitar music)My hands are cold.It's a pretty cold studio.", 'The coldest studio.', 'Usually can do this.There I just want to do it once.(guitar strumming)', 'When I first heard Bob Dylanwas, I think, about threeyears ago in Minneapolis.', "At that time Iwas just sort of doing nothing.I was there working, I guess.I was making pretend I wasgoing to school out there.I'd just come there from South Dakota.", "You've sungnow at Goody's here in town.Have you sung at any of the coffee houses?"]
```

Comment: I think this is to find out the sentences, but not paragraphs. I understand that the paragraph identification is a hard task and the border is subtle, but if you can suggest me any other library rather than nltk.tokenize.texttiling that would be much appreciated.